# google cloud vision OCR not reading the vowels in Arabic

Tags: google-cloud-vision

google cloud vision ocr has a higher than 99% success rate in reading Arabic characters.  I find it strange therefore that they would neglect the vowels.  It's gotta be the case that there is some option where I can enable google to detect the vowels.  Let me just give an example in case I'm not being clear.  In the word صيف the short vowel is not transcribed but in the صيفُ it is since the final 'u' is written down.  Google cloud will not transcribe that final u.  I would think if this feature were available it would be listed here:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages

But I don't see anything.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like a specific language feature, I would suggest to file this a feature request so that engineers might take notice and other users as well for this feature. https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

[Vision OCR Template.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=0)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try your image with version builtin/weekly https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#feature